# WeightedRandomSampler with multi-dimensional batch

Tags: pytorch, classification, multiclass-classification, pytorch-dataloader, imbalanced-data

I'm working on a classification problem (100 classes) and my dataset has a huge class imbalance. To tackle this, I'm considering using torch's `WeightedRandomSampler` to oversample the minority class. I took help from [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-there-a-limit-on-how-disbalanced-a-train-set-can-be/26334/6) which seemed pretty straightforward. Only concern with this is the nature of my dataset.

In my case, each sample (1 point in a batch) contains 8 points. Each of these 8 points have one true class out of 100 classes. So my output shape is like this: `(bs x 8)`. Hence, the final weight variable has `total_dataset_length*8` length.

Here's my implementation:

```
y_org = np.load('target.npy')                 # 5000 x 8
samples_per_class = np.unique(y_org.ravel(), return_counts=True)[1]

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight='balanced', \
                                                  classes=np.unique(y_org.ravel()), \
                                                  y=y_org.ravel())
weights = class_weights[y_org.ravel()]
sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(weights, len(y_org.ravel()), replacement=True)
```

To count the number of occurrences of class index, I have to unroll (ravel) the ground truth array along the first dimension. Since the final `weight` variable has `total_dataset_length*8`, it causes indexing errors during loading

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I use WeightedRandomSampler in such cases?